# Ctrl R not showing latest history

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

On mac when I try to search my history of commands I get only very old commands. No new command is saved in history. 
[image]

You see here that after history I did a command `fdfsdfsd` but then if I reopen the terminal I get this:
[image] 
For the last few weeks no history is being saved... What can it be?

Comment: Check a couple posts.... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218731/why-bash-history-on-my-mac-wont-save and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220897/bash-history-is-not-remembered-in-terminal